# Changes sides of lstlisting line numbering when switching pages

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I am currently writing some tesxt for my masters thesis.
I have a coste listing which expands on two pages. I would like the listing to change sides of line numbering when switching the page.
Is there any command for this?
Thanks in advance

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
language=C++,             
basicstyle=\footnotesize, 
numbers=left,                 
numberstyle=\footnotesize,    
stepnumber=1,                  
numbersep=5pt,                 
backgroundcolor=\color{white},         
\usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,         
showstringspaces=false,   
showtabs=false,     
frame=single,       
tabsize=2,          
captionpos=b,           
breaklines=true,        
breakatwhitespace=false,
escapeinside={\%*}{*)} 
}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={}, label={lst:label}, language=C]
function()
{   
code
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, do i understand it correctly, that you want to have the line numbers always at the outside (or inside), and not on the left side? Can you extend your snippet to a [compilable minimal example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) so we see your basic setup? it also saves time building an own testcase.

Comment: Johannes_B yes I want the line numbers to be at the left OR right, depending on the page number.

Comment: Line numbers should always be at the left, in my opinion; if a line is short, a line number at the right margin will be almost unreachable without using a ruler for guiding the eyes to it.